# Handling arguments in a Python-like range() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, iterator, ecmascript-6

I'm making a Python-like `range()` function (see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range)) using JavaScript. This function can take from 1 to 3 arguments. There are 3 variables (`start`, `stop` and `step`) that need to have some value, either from arguments, or a default value.

- If only one argument is passed, `start` is `0`, `stop` is the first argument and `step` is `1`.
- If two arguments are passed, `start` is the first argument, `stop` is the second argument and `step` is `1`.
- If three arguments are passed, `start` is the first argument, `stop` is the second argument and `step` is the third argument.

I'm aware that since ECMAScript 6 JavaScript has [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), but the situation here is more complex. Therefore, I used [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get an array of all arguments and then assign them to appropriate variables.

```
const range = (...args) => {
  if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 3) {
    throw new Error('This function takes between 1 and 3 arguments')
  }
  const [start, stop, step] = {
    1: [0, ...args, 1]
   ,2: [...args, 1]
   ,3: args
  }[args.length]
}
```

I'm using the solution presented in the article [Replacing switch statements with Object literals](https://toddmotto.com/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals/). The object keys are numbers of arguments and values are arrays with values for `start`, `stop` and `step`. I select the array which matches `args.length` and use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the array elements respectively to `start`, `stop` and `step`.

This code is quite short, but I'm not sure whether it's readable. I came up with an alternative solution, using simple `if-else` blocks. I have to declare the variables at the beginning here, because `let` and `const` are block-scoped, so declaring them inside the `if-else` blocks would have no effect on the rest of the function.

```
const range = (...args) => {
  let [start, stop, step]
  if (args.length === 1) {
    ;[start, stop, step] = [0, ...args, 1]
  } else if (args.length === 2) {
    ;[start, stop, step] = [...args, 1]
  } else if (args.length === 3) {
    ;[start, stop, step] = args
  } else {
    throw new Error('This function takes between 1 and 3 arguments')
  }
}
```

This version maybe is more readable, but I don't like it very much. It repeats the `[start, stop, step]` fragment four times, and also I can't use `const` (and I'm trying to use `const` whenever possible).

Another solution that came to my mind is to assume as default the situation when two or three parameters are passed, and when one parameters is passed, assign `start` to `stop` and `0` to `start`.

```
const range = function(start, stop, step = 1) {
  if (arguments.length < 1 || arguments.length > 3) {
    throw new Error('This function takes between 1 and 3 arguments')
  }
  if (stop === undefined) {
    ;[start, stop] = [0, start]
  }
}
```

This also doesn't look good to me. I think that for someone reading this code it would be very difficult to understand what it does. Also, this code forces me to use a regular function instead of arrow function (because arrow functions don't have `arguments`) and violates two ESLint rules which I'm using: [`prefer-rest-params`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params) and [`no-param-reassign`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign).

What is the best way to solve this problem? Should I modify one of the solutions that I already have, or should I try something completely different?

#### Edit

I made a variation of the third option which doesn't violate any of my ESLint rules:

```
const range = (...args) => {
  if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 3) {
    throw new Error('This function takes between 1 and 3 arguments')
  }
  let [start, stop, step = 1] = args
  if (stop === undefined) {
    ;[start, stop] = [0, start]
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, aside from handling invalid number of arguments, it's possible to do this in one line: `const [start, stop, step] = [[0, ...args, 1], [...args, 1], args][args.length - 1]` but that's extremely unreadable.

Comment: Saying of the 3rd example that "I think that for someone reading this code it would be very difficult to understand what it does" is absurd.  It's quite clear imo, and probably the best of the three.  The first example is the most "difficult," but still clear enough to anyone familiar with es6, and rather clever.  The if else version is the worst to my taste, but all are fine.  Why do you begin lines with `;`?

Comment: @Jonah I'm using [npm's coding style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#semicolons).

Comment: I like the edited version.  I'd replace the `if` statement with `;[start, stop] = stop === undefined ? [0, start] : [start, stop]`.  fair enough on the npm style guide, though fwiw i think it's pretty nasty.  i prefer guidelines like these: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript.  but, style of that sort isn't something i care too much about....

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167537/javascript-python-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the edited version.  I'd suggest just one small change:

```
const range = (...args) => {
  if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 3) {
    throw new Error('This function takes between 1 and 3 arguments')
  }
  let [start, stop, step = 1] = args
  ;[start, stop] = (stop === undefined) ? [0, start] : [start, stop]
}
```

Aside from reducing the visual clutter of the `if` statement, in general I find that expressions (which always execute) are easier to reason about than branching statements, even though the resulting logic is the same.