# A JavaScript implementation of the Python's range() function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

Recently I implemented the Python's `range()` function in JavaScript. The function has three parameters: `start`, `stop` and `step`. The range includes elements from `start` and up to, but not including `stop`. The `step` parameter defaults to `1` and specifies the distance between two elements.

It uses [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (an ECMAScript 6 feature) to generate properties on-demand, so for example `range(0, -1000000000, -3)[12345678]` executes immediately, without computing all elements in the range.

For more information see the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Gothdo/range). See also related question: [Handling arguments in a Python-like range() function in JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145472/97338).

The project consists of two files `index.js` and `array-indices-proxy.js`. The former is (obviously) the main file, and the latter is a class which works like Proxy, but invokes the traps only for array indices.

`index.js`:

```
import values from 'babel-runtime/core-js/array/values';
import head from 'lodash.head';
import last from 'lodash.last';
import ArrayIndicesProxy from './array-indices-proxy';

const mandatory = (parameter) => {
  throw new Error(`The ${parameter} parameter is mandatory`);
};

export class PythonRange {
  constructor(...args) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      throw new Error(`Expected at least 1 argument, got ${args.length}`);
    }
    if (args.length > 3) {
      throw new Error(`Expected at most 3 arguments, got ${args.length}`);
    }
    if (!args.every(Number.isInteger)) {
      throw new Error('All arguments must be integers');
    }

    const step = args[2] !== undefined ? args[2] : 1;
    if (step === 0) {
      throw new Error('The step argument must not be zero');
    }
    let [start, stop] = args;
    [start, stop] = (stop === undefined) ? [0, start] : [start, stop];
    const baseDescriptor = {
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
    };
    Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'start', { ...baseDescriptor, value: start });
    Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'stop', { ...baseDescriptor, value: stop });
    Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'step', { ...baseDescriptor, value: step });

    Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false,
      get() {
        const length = Math.ceil((this.stop - this.start) / this.step);
        return Math.max(0, length);
      },
    });

    Reflect.defineProperty(this, Symbol.toStringTag, {
      configurable: false,
      writable: false,
      enumerable: false,
      value: 'PythonRange',
    });

    // Prevent the length property from being modified.
    // We can't just set it as non-writable, because it has a getter.
    const proxy = new Proxy(this, {
      set(target, property, value) {
        return (property === 'length') ? false : Reflect.set(target, property, value);
      },
      deleteProperty() {
        return false;
      },
      // In order to be able to create numeric properties on-demand,
      // the object has to be extensible.
      preventExtensions() {
        return false;
      },
    });

    const indicesProxy = new ArrayIndicesProxy(proxy, {
      get(target, index) {
        if (index < target.length) {
          return target.start + (target.step * index);
        }
        return undefined;
      },
      has(target, index) {
        return index < target.length;
      },
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, index) {
        const descriptor = {
          value: indicesProxy[index],
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false,
        };
        // It is neccessary to define this property on target, because proxy cannot
        // report a non-existing property as non-configurable.
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40921884/3853934
        Reflect.defineProperty(target, String(index), descriptor);
        return descriptor;
      },
      defineProperty() {
        return false;
      },
      set() {
        return false;
      },
    });

    return indicesProxy;
  }
  forEach(callback = mandatory('callback'), thisArg = this, ...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected at most two arguments; got ${rest.length + 2}`);
    }
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, callback, thisArg);
  }
  includes(value = mandatory('value'), ...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected one argument; got ${rest.length + 1}`);
    }
    if (!Number.isInteger(value)) {
      throw new Error('The value argument must be an integer');
    }
    return (this.step > 0
        ? value >= this.start && value < this.stop
        : value > this.stop && value <= this.start)
      && (value - this.start) % this.step === 0;
  }
  min(...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected zero arguments; got ${rest.length}`);
    }
    if (this.length !== 0) {
      return this.step > 0 ? head(this) : last(this);
    }
    return Infinity;
  }
  max(...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected zero arguments; got ${rest.length}`);
    }
    if (this.length !== 0) {
      return this.step > 0 ? last(this) : head(this);
    }
    return -Infinity;
  }
  reverse(...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected zero arguments; got ${rest.length}`);
    }
    [this.start, this.stop, this.step] = [
      last(this),
      this.start - Math.sign(this.step),
      -this.step,
    ];
    return this;
  }
  toString() {
    return `range(${this.start}, ${this.stop}, ${this.step})`;
  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.toString();
  }
  inspect() {
    return this.toString();
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return values(this);
  }
  static areEqual(a = mandatory('a'), b = mandatory('b'), ...rest) {
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      throw new Error(`Expected two arguments; got ${rest.length + 2}`);
    }
    if (![a, b].every(x => x instanceof PythonRange)) {
      throw new Error('Both arguments must be instances of PythonRange');
    }
    // Based on https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cff677abe1823900e954592035a170eb67840971/Objects/rangeobject.c#L425
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
    if (a.length === 0) return true;
    if (a.start !== b.start) return false;
    if (a.length === 1) return true;
    return a.step === b.step;
  }
}
export default function range(...args) {
  return new PythonRange(...args);
}
```

`array-indices-proxy.js`:

```
import fromPairs from 'lodash.frompairs';

export default class ArrayIndicesProxy {
  constructor(targetArray, handler) {
    const newHandler = fromPairs(Object.entries(handler).map(([name, trap]) => {
      const propertyAccessTraps = ['defineProperty', 'deleteProperty', 'get', 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor', 'has', 'set'];
      if (propertyAccessTraps.includes(name)) {
        return [name, (target, property, ...other) => {
          if (typeof property !== 'symbol') {
            const parsed = parseInt(property, 10);
            const maxArrayLength = 4294967295;
            if (parsed >= 0 && parsed <= maxArrayLength) {
              return trap(target, parsed, ...other);
            }
          }
          return Reflect[name](target, property, ...other);
        }];
      }
      return [name, trap];
    }));
    return new Proxy(targetArray, newHandler);
  }
}
```

I also made tests using Mocha, Chai and Sinon.

`test.js`:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { isClass } from 'typechecker';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import range, { PythonRange } from '../src/index';

describe('range', () => {
  it('returns an instance of PythonRange', () => {
    expect(range(10)).to.be.an.instanceof(PythonRange);
  });
});

describe('PythonRange', () => {
  it('is a class', () => {
    expect(isClass(PythonRange)).to.be.true;
  });
  describe('handling incorrect arguments', () => {
    it('throws an error when called with less than one argument', () => {
      expect(() => range()).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('throws an error when called with more than three arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(1, 2, 3, 4)).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('throws an error when called with non-integer arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(1.2)).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(true)).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(1, 2, '3')).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('throws an error when the step argument is zero', () => {
      expect(() => range(1, 2, 0)).to.throw(Error);
    });
  });
  describe('start, stop, and step properties', () => {
    let r;
    before(() => {
      r = range(1, 11, 2);
    });
    it('have correct values', () => {
      expect(r.start).to.equal(1);
      expect(r.stop).to.equal(11);
      expect(r.step).to.equal(2);
    });
    it('are non-configurable, non-enumerable and writable', () => {
      ['start', 'stop', 'step']
        .map(property => Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(r, property))
        .forEach(descriptor => expect(descriptor).to.deep.equal({
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: false,
          writable: true,
          value: descriptor.value,
        }));
    });
    it('changing them updates the length property', () => {
      r.start = 0;
      expect(r.length).to.equal(6);
      r.stop = 8;
      expect(r.length).to.equal(4);
      r.step = 1;
      expect(r.length).to.equal(8);
    });
  });
  describe('length property', () => {
    it('has the correct value', () => {
      expect(range(10)).to.have.property('length', 10);
      expect(range(1, 6)).to.have.property('length', 5);
      expect(range(1, 11, 2)).to.have.property('length', 5);
      expect(range(1, 12, 2)).to.have.property('length', 6);
      expect(range(1, 1)).to.have.property('length', 0);
      expect(range(-10)).to.have.property('length', 0);
      expect(range(-10, -15, -6)).to.have.property('length', 1);
      expect(range(0, -10, -1)).to.have.property('length', 10);
    });
    it('is non-configurable and non-enumerable', () => {
      const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(range(10), 'length');
      expect(descriptor.configurable).to.be.false;
      expect(descriptor.enumerable).to.be.false;
    });
    it('cannot be modified', () => {
      const r = range(10);
      expect(Reflect.set(r, 'length', 15)).to.be.false;
      expect(r.length).to.equal(10);
    });
  });
  describe('numeric properties', () => {
    it('exist', () => {
      const r = range(2);
      expect(-1 in r).to.be.false;
      expect(0 in r).to.be.true;
      expect(1 in r).to.be.true;
      expect(3 in r).to.be.false;
    });
    it('have correct values', () => {
      let r = range(3);
      expect(r[-1]).to.be.undefined;
      expect(r[0]).to.equal(0);
      expect(r[1]).to.equal(1);
      expect(r[2]).to.equal(2);
      expect(r[3]).to.be.undefined;

      r = range(4, 5);
      expect(r[-1]).to.be.undefined;
      expect(r[0]).to.equal(4);
      expect(r[1]).to.be.undefined;

      r = range(3, 6, 2);
      expect(r[0]).to.equal(3);
      expect(r[1]).to.equal(5);

      r = range(2, 0, -1);
      expect(r[0]).to.equal(2);
      expect(r[1]).to.equal(1);
    });
    it('are non-configurable, enumerable and non-writable', () => {
      expect(Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(range(1, 2), '0')).to.deep.equal({
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false,
        value: 1,
      });
    });
    it('cannot be reassigned', () => {
      expect(Reflect.set(range(10), '0', 42)).to.be.false;
    });
    it('cannot be changed using defineProperty', () => {
      expect(Reflect.defineProperty(range(10), '0', {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false,
        value: 42,
      })).to.be.false;
    });
    it('cannot be deleted', () => {
      expect(Reflect.deleteProperty(range(10), '0')).to.be.false;
    });
  });
  it('cannot be made non-extensible', () => {
    expect(Reflect.preventExtensions(range(10))).to.be.false;
  });
  describe('#forEach', () => {
    it('throws an error for invalid arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(3).forEach()).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(3).forEach(42)).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(3).forEach(class {})).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(3).forEach(() => {}, () => {}, () => {})).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('iterates over the range', () => {
      const spy = sinon.spy();
      const r = range(3, -4, -2);
      r.forEach(spy);
      expect(spy.args).to.deep.equal([
        [3, 0, r],
        [1, 1, r],
        [-1, 2, r],
        [-3, 3, r],
      ]);
    });
    it('uses the provided value as this', () => {
      const spy = sinon.spy();
      const r = range(1);
      const thisArg = {};
      r.forEach(spy, thisArg);
      expect(spy.calledOn(thisArg));
    });
  });
  describe('#includes', () => {
    it('throws an error for invalid arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(3).includes()).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(3).includes('1')).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => range(3).includes(3, 5)).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('returns true if the range includes the specifed number', () => {
      expect(range(3).includes(0)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(3).includes(2)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(2, 5).includes(2)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(2, 5).includes(3)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(2, 5).includes(4)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(10)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(8)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(2)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(-5, 0).includes(-5)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(-10, -5).includes(-6)).to.be.true;
      expect(range(-5, 5).includes(2)).to.be.true;
    });
    it('returns false if the range doesn\'t include the specified number', () => {
      expect(range(3).includes(-1)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(3).includes(3)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(2, 5).includes(1)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(2, 5).includes(5)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(11)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(9)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).includes(0)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(-5, 0).includes(0)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(-5, 0).includes(5)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(-10, -5).includes(-5)).to.be.false;
      expect(range(-10, -5).includes(-1)).to.be.false;
    });
  });
  describe('#min', () => {
    it('throws an error for invalid arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(3).min(1)).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('returns the smallest value in the range', () => {
      expect(range(0).min()).to.equal(Infinity);
      expect(range(3).min()).to.equal(0);
      expect(range(2, 4).min()).to.equal(2);
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).min()).to.equal(2);
    });
  });
  describe('#max', () => {
    it('throws an error for invalid arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(3).max(1)).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('returns the largest value in the range', () => {
      expect(range(0).max()).to.equal(-Infinity);
      expect(range(3).max()).to.equal(2);
      expect(range(2, 4).max()).to.equal(3);
      expect(range(10, 0, -2).max()).to.equal(10);
    });
  });
  describe('#reverse', () => {
    it('throws an error when called with more than 0 arguments', () => {
      expect(() => range(3).reverse(true)).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('changes the original range', () => {
      const r = range(3);
      r.reverse();
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(r, range(2, -1, -1)));
    });
    it('returns the range', () => {
      const r = range(3);
      expect(r === r.reverse()).to.be.true;
    });
    it('reverses the range', () => {
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(3).reverse(), range(2, -1, -1))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(2, 5).reverse(), range(4, 1, -1))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(0, 10, 2).reverse(), range(8, -1, -2))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(0, 3, 3).reverse(), range(0, 1))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(10, 0, -1).reverse(), range(1, 11, 1))).to.be.true;
    });
  });
  describe('@@iterator', () => {
    it('iterates the range', () => {
      const result = [];
      for (const element of range(3)) { // eslint-disable-line
        result.push(element);
      }
      expect(result).to.deep.equal([0, 1, 2]);
    });
  });
  describe('@@toStringTag', () => {
    it('equals to "PythonRange"', () => {
      expect(range(3)[Symbol.toStringTag]).to.equal('PythonRange');
    });
  });
  describe('#toString', () => {
    it('returns a string representation of the range', () => {
      expect(range(3).toString()).to.equal('range(0, 3, 1)');
      expect(range(4, 2, -1).toString()).to.equal('range(4, 2, -1)');
    });
  });
  describe('#valueOf', () => {
    it('returns the result of toString() method', () => {
      expect(range(3).valueOf()).to.equal(range(3).toString());
      expect(range(4, 2, -1).valueOf()).to.equal(range(4, 2, -1).toString());
    });
  });
  describe('#inspect', () => {
    it('returns the result of toString() method', () => {
      expect(range(3).inspect()).to.equal(range(3).toString());
      expect(range(4, 2, -1).inspect()).to.equal(range(4, 2, -1).toString());
    });
  });
  describe('PythonRange.areEqual()', () => {
    it('throws an error for invalid arguments', () => {
      expect(() => PythonRange.areEqual()).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => PythonRange.areEqual(range(3))).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => PythonRange.areEqual(1, 2)).to.throw(Error);
      expect(() => PythonRange.areEqual(range(3), range(4), range(5))).to.throw(Error);
    });
    it('returns true if the ranges are equal', () => {
      const r = range(2);
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(r, r)).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(0, 3), range(3))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(0), range(5, 5))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(3), range(3))).to.be.true;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(3, 10, 15), range(3, 11, 15))).to.be.true;
    });
    it('returns false if the ranges are not equal', () => {
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(3), range(4))).to.be.false;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(2, 3), range(3, 4))).to.be.false;
      expect(PythonRange.areEqual(range(0, 5, 1), range(0, 5, 2))).to.be.false;
    });
  });
});
```

`array-indices-proxy.js`:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import fromPairs from 'lodash.frompairs';
import ArrayIndicesProxy from '../src/array-indices-proxy';

const checkTrap = (name, ...args) => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(Reflect[name]);
  const target = [1, 2];
  const proxy = new ArrayIndicesProxy(target, {
    [name]: spy,
  });
  const properties = ['-1', '0', '1', '2', 'test', 'constructor'];
  properties.forEach(property => Reflect[name](proxy, property, ...args));
  expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(3);
  expect(spy.calledWith(target, 0)).to.be.true;
  expect(spy.calledWith(target, 1)).to.be.true;
  expect(spy.calledWith(target, 2)).to.be.true;
};

describe('ArrayIndicesProxy', () => {
  describe('property access traps', () => {
    it('invokes the trap only for array indices', () => {
      checkTrap('defineProperty', { configurable: true, enumerable: true });
      checkTrap('deleteProperty');
      checkTrap('get');
      checkTrap('getOwnPropertyDescriptor');
      checkTrap('has');
      checkTrap('set', true);
    });
    it('calls the appropriate Reflect methods on the target for properties which are not array indices', () => {
      const propertyAccessTraps = ['defineProperty', 'deleteProperty', 'get', 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor', 'has', 'set'];
      const handler = fromPairs(propertyAccessTraps.map(name => [name, () => {}]));
      const proxy = new ArrayIndicesProxy([1, 2, 3], handler);
      Reflect.defineProperty(proxy, 'test', { configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: 42 });
      expect(proxy).to.have.property('test', 42);
      Reflect.deleteProperty(proxy, 'test');
      expect(proxy).to.not.have.property('test');
      Reflect.set(proxy, 'test2', 43);
      expect(proxy).to.have.property('test2', 43);
      expect(Reflect.get(proxy, 'test2')).to.equal(43);
      expect(Reflect.has(proxy, 'test2')).to.equal(true);
      expect(Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proxy, 'test2')).to.deep.equal({
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: 43,
      });
    });
  });
  describe('other traps', () => {
    it('are not affected', () => {
      const proxy = new ArrayIndicesProxy([1, 2, 3], { ownKeys: () => ['0', '1', '2', 'length', 'test'] });
      expect(Reflect.ownKeys(proxy)).to.deep.equal(['0', '1', '2', 'length', 'test']);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Those many exceptions make the code, uh, verbose, but I suppose that's good :-)

Comment: @Bergi I just wanted to make my code [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). One the things that annoy me in JavaScript is that it doesn't throw an error when you try to do something that doesn't make any sense, like [adding an array and an object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/3853934). When you debug code, an error message like "you passed too few arguments" is IMO far more helpful than "cannot access property of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a few observations:

- The name `PythonRange` could simply be `Range` - that it is inspired by Python could be in the documentation, but doesn't change anything.
- All those parameter type / interface checking is not a bad thing (you know its advantages), but it makes your code very verbose. You might want to look into AOP to extract this in some higher-order helper functions.
- Why use `defineProperty` to create non-configurable and non-enumerable properties? This doesn't seem necessary, and slows the execution down in a few engines.
- Why not define the `length` getter and `Symbol.toStringTag` on the prototype?
- That proxy to "*prevent the length property from being modified*" is totally pointless. `length` doesn't have a setter, so it throws anyway on attempts to modify it.
- The `ArrayIndicesProxy` is a really nice abstraction
- The biggest issue: why are your ranges mutable? [Python ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) definitely are immutable. Mutation will make iteration really complicated.
  `reverse` should return a new range instead of overwriting the instance in-place.
- Using `parseInt` in the test for array-index-ness doesn't work. It doesn't consider leading zeroes and other things. Better use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163612/1048572)

(I have not read the tests)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I used `PythonRange` because browsers already have [a `Range` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range). Making properties non-configurable and non-enumerable might be superfluous indeed, but I wanted to make that for example if something shouldn't be deleted, then it can't be deleted. I know that Python ranges are immutable, but I don't see any reason for that. What do you mean by "Mutation will make iteration really complicated."?

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the builtin `Range`, but still I'd prefer something like `IntegerRange` over `Python…`. Regarding immutability, I can only see advantages of it - it should be the default rather than the option. Mutating the range while iterating it will lead to confusing effects.