# JavaScript Python Arrays

Tags: javascript, array, iterator, meta-programming

Here is an implementation in JavaScript that attempts to resemble Python-like arrays by mimicking slice comprehension for both getters and setters, as well as negative indexing from the end of the list. I've called it `List` just because; this name has no particular importance to me, so suggestions on better naming for this are also welcome:

```js
const List = (function () { // IIFE
  // proxy handler
  const listHandler = {
    get(target, property) {
      const strProp = String(property)
      const generator = slice(strProp)

      // slice comprehension
      if (generator !== null) {
        return List.from(new Map(generator(target)).values())
      }

      const length = target.length
      const index = parseInt(Number(strProp))

      // negative index lookup
      if (index == property && index >= -length && index < 0) {
        return target[index + length]
      }

      // prototype chain
      return target[property]
    },

    set(target, property, value) {
      const strProp = String(property)
      const length = target.length
      const generator = slice(strProp)

      // slice comprehension
      if (generator !== null) {
        // can't use `in` on primitives
        if (!(Symbol.iterator in Object(value))) {
          throw new TypeError('can only assign an iterable')
        }

        const [start, stop, step] = generator.indices(length)

        // non-extended slice
        if (step === 1) {
          target.splice(start, stop - start, ...value)
        // extended slice with matching iterable length
        } else {
          if (isNaN(value.length)) {
            throw new TypeError('cannot assign iterator to extended slice')
          }

          if (Math.floor((stop - start) / step) !== value.length) {
            throw new RangeError('mismatching length of iterable and slice')
          }

          let iteration = 0

          for (const [index] of generator(target)) {
            target[index] = value[iteration++]
          }
        }

        return value
      }

      const index = parseInt(Number(strProp))

      // negative index lookup
      if (index == property && index >= -length && index < 0) {
        return target[index + length] = value
      }

      // fallback
      return target[property] = value
    }
  }

  // expose class definition
  return class List extends Array {
    static from(arrayLike) {
      return Array.from.apply(this, arguments)
    }

    static of() {
      return Array.of.apply(this, arguments)
    }

    static slice(start, stop = null, step = null) {
      if (arguments.length === 0) {
        throw new TypeError('expected at least 1 argument, got 0')
      }

      if (arguments.length > 3) {
        throw new TypeError('expected at most 3 arguments, got ' + arguments.length)
      }

      const generator = slice([
        start === null ? '' : start,
        stop === null ? '' : stop,
        step === null ? '' : step
      ].join(':'))

      if (generator === null) {
        throw new TypeError('arguments must be numeric or null')
      }

      return generator
    }

    constructor() {
      super(...arguments)

      return new Proxy(this, listHandler)
    }
  }

  function indices([start, stop, step], length) {
    step = !step.trim() || isNaN(step) ? 1 : Number(step)

    if (step > 0) {
      start = !start.trim() || isNaN(start) ? 0 : Number(start)
      stop = !stop.trim() || isNaN(stop) ? length : Math.max(start, Number(stop))

      start = Math.max(-length, Math.min(start, length))
      stop = Math.max(-length, Math.min(stop, length))
    } else {
      start = !start.trim() || isNaN(start) ? length - 1 : Number(start)
      stop = !stop.trim() || isNaN(stop) ? -length - 1 : Math.min(start, Number(stop))

      start = Math.max(-length - 1, Math.min(start, length - 1))
      stop = Math.max(-length - 1, Math.min(stop, length - 1))
    }

    if (start < 0) start += length
    if (stop < 0) stop += length

    return [start, stop, step]
  }

  function slice(property) {
    const result = property.match(/^(-?\d*):(-?\d*):?(-?\d*)$/)

    if (result === null) {
      return result
    }

    const range = result.slice(1, 4)

    if (range[2] == 0) {
      throw new RangeError('slice step cannot be zero')
    }

    function* entries(array) {
      const [start, stop, step] = indices(range, array.length)

      for (let index = start; step > 0 ? index < stop : index > stop; index += step) {
        yield [index, array[index]]
      }
    }

    entries.valueOf = function valueOf() {
      return range.slice()
    }

    entries.toString = function toString() {
      return property
    }

    entries.indices = indices.bind(entries, range)

    return entries
  }
})() // end IIFE

// Demo Here
let list = new List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
let slice = List.slice(-2, -5, -1)

console.log('list:', list.join())
console.log('list[-2]:', list[-2])
console.log('slice:', slice.toString())
console.log('slice.indices(list.length):', slice.indices(list.length).join())
console.log('list[slice]:', list[slice].join())
console.log('list["-2:-5:-1"]:', list['-2:-5:-1'].join())

list[slice] = 'bcd'

console.log('list[slice] = "bcd":', list.join())
```

My goal is a consistent and readable implementation that follows the Python spec as closely as JavaScriptly possible, meaning I still want the behavior to somewhat resemble JavaScript.

For example instead of throwing `RangeError` for accessing or assigning indices out of range, I resolve the property access or assignment on the `target` object like normal arrays would allow. Details like that are for the sake of following expected JavaScript conventions.

Any feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Input validation

Here, the validation of arguments comes after using them in a method call:

> ```
>   const generator = slice([
>     start === null ? '' : start,
>     stop === null ? '' : stop,
>     step === null ? '' : step
>   ].join(':'))
>
>   if (generator === null) {
>     throw new TypeError('arguments must be numeric or null')
>   }
> ```

That's not a good practice in general,
because it's potentially passing garbage to `slice`,
and too indirect,
since the actual validation logic is not visible here.

It would be better and easier to read if the validation logic was explicitly visible.
Perhaps a `validateArgs` method that takes `start, stop, step` and either throws an exception or returns an array of 3 values that are valid.

#### Usability

The default value of `step` is `null`, but that's invalid.
It would be better to make it 1.

#### Don't repeat yourself

This piece of code appears twice:

> ```
>   const index = parseInt(Number(strProp))
>
>   // negative index lookup
>   if (index == property && index >= -length && index < 0) {
>     return target[index + length]
>   }
>
>   // prototype chain
>   return target[property]
> ```

It would be better to move this to a helper method.

#### Ordering of terms in conditions

Instead of this:

> ```
>   if (index == property && index >= -length && index < 0) {
> ```

I recommend this ordering of terms:

```
  if (index == property && -length <= index && index < 0) {
```

When the terms are in increasing order,
the condition may be slightly easier to read.
Since we're talking about Python,
note that this condition would be written in Python as `-length <= index < 0`.

#### Ternary as loop condition

The ternary operator is often not easy to read.
Also,
the `step > 0` will be evaluated in every iteration,
even though it doesn't change.

> ```
>   for (let index = start; step > 0 ? index < stop : index > stop; index += step) {
>     yield [index, array[index]]
>   }
> ```

It would be better to rewrite this either by lifting the `step > 0` condition out of the loop and write two similar loops,
or to use a generator for indexes and loop over that.

Comment: I appreciate all of your feedback, I just wanted to ask to be sure you were aware of the "usability" point though. The default is `null` but within the scoped "private" `slice` function, `null` becomes `1` so it's still the de-facto default, I just didn't want `1` to be explicit in the notation string generated when it isn't explicitly specified. In light of that, do you still feel I should default the public function's `step` to `1`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I meant that `List.slice(1, 2)` fails, and it would be nice if it defaulted `step = 1`. Even so, it would be good to omit the `1` from the notation string.

Comment: are you sure it fails? I can't test at the moment, but I did try running with two arguments before and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I copy-pasted your code in Chrome's JavaScript console. If I run `Slice.list(1, 2)` I get `Uncaught RangeError: slice step cannot be zero`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh jeez that's a bug. Thank you for pointing that out, I had thought that `"" != 0`, and I could have sworn I had tested that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts welcome to JavaScript :-) (Check out this related short video: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: I've seen that video a long time ago and I am very familiar with the dubious non-strict equality table for JavaScript, I just thought I had tested that particular case and my guess is I had made a slight edit between testing that case and posting that broke it.